# Doctrine2 findAll() method not grabbing associated data?

Tags: php, orm, doctrine, mapping, associations

I have a very simple question.  Currently I'm using Doctrine2's `findAll()` method after the `getRepository` method and I have a simple `OneToOne` relationship setup (`Manufacturers` has a field `address_id` that links to `Addresses`, basic stuff).  I'm trying to populate a table with one field from the `Manufacturer` and the rest of the fields with data from the associated `Address`.

I'm doing this in my view code:

```
<?php foreach($instances as $instance) { ?>
<?php $address = $instance->address; ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $instance->name; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $address->street; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $address->city; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $address->state; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $address->zip; ?></td>
  </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

where `$instances` is every entry in the `Manufacturers` table.  Every property is public but for some reason Doctrine2 just won't pull the associated `Address` data along with the call to `findAll()` `Manufacturers`.  What am I doing wrong?

This is what I'm using to grab the data:

```
$instances = $this->doctrine->em->getRepository('Entities\Manufacturer')->findAll();
```

Do I need to somehow specify to Doctrine that I want to grab associated data as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default all doctrine associations are lazy loading. Doctrine is using proxy objects to make lazy loading of associated data possible. For each field getters are created in the proxy class. You just have to call the getters instead of directly accessing public properties. 
It is recommended to declare all your fields private in your entity and define getters and setters for them.

Comment: Thanks!  I actually ended up finding a similar question here and changed my classes accordingly, it works now!

Comment: Be careful with lazy loading. Even though it's easy to deal with object from the app layer, chances are you are issuing multiple queries. I'd suggest tailing your query log and making sure you optimize by reducing the number of queries by avoiding lazy loading and forcing Doctrine to pull all the data at once.

Comment: Nice addon Mike. In most cases you want to define a oneToOne association as eager, because you are likely to deal with the associated data as well. This way you will issue a single query.